# How to convert a Subsink api call to Promise.all within Angular9?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, promise, angular-material

I have the following `async` function which uses `Subsink`

```
import {SubSink} from 'subsink';
...
...
async retryClick() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.Id.length; i++) {
            const res = await this.serviceC.status(this.hostName[i]);
            const qId =  res.rows[0].qid;
            const oretry: ORInterface = {
                oQId: qId,
                reason: this.reason
            };
            this.subs.sink = this.serviceB.retry(oretry)
                .subscribe(s => {
                    if (i === this.serverId.length - 1) {
                        this.dialog.close();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

I want to write the above code using `Promise.all`

```
Promise.all(this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map(hostName =>
            this.serviceC.status(hostName)
                .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0].qid))
        )).then(() => this.dialog.close());
```

The above code is working fine using `Promise.all`
Here `Id` is of type `any`

How to add `oretry: ORInterface` and remaining statements in the above `Promise.all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of guesswork (and assuming that `this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map(...)` is correct) it appears that you are trying to do this ...

```
Promise.all(this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map((hostName) => {
    return this.serviceC.status(hostName)
    .then(res => {
        // Here `this.serviceB.retry(oretry).subscribe` must be promisified, 
        // in order to keep the promise chain, thence `Promise.all()` informed.
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            const oretry: ORInterface = {
                'oQId': res.rows[0].qid,
                'reason': this.reason
            };
            this.serviceB.retry(oretry).subscribe(resolve); // No need to test if (i === this.serverId.length - 1). 
                                                            // The last .subscribe(resolve) to fire will trigger this.dialog.close() below
        });
    });
}))
.then(() => {
    this.dialog.close();
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    this.dialog.close(); // presumably
});
```

... but note that the last `.subscribe(resolve)` to fire will not necessarily correspond with the final `this.serviceC.status(hostName)` call. The Promises returned by `.map()` will (in all liklihood) settle in any order; that's the nature of asynchronism. This may or may not matter to your application.